# Executing chef test from a rakefile

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, teamcity, chefspec

I have some chef unit tests that I can run via the command : `chef exec rspec`

However, I am trying to run these from TeamCity and I am using a rakefile. When I try to execute the rakefile the require 'chefspec' line in the test file causes an error `"cannot load such file  -- chefspec (LoadError)"`

I know chefspec is installed. I am new to Ruby, chefspec, rspec. I know there is mention of a gemspec file and I have tried to create one in the directory where I can run the command `chef exec rspec` to execute the test. However, when I try to run `bundle install` I get the error `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`. Is there a default location of a gemfile when you install ruby? I am pretty lost at this point.

`C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require': cannot load such file -- chefspec (LoadErr
or)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from D:/../spec/octopus_tentacle_spec.rb:1:in`'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in`block in load_
spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in`load_spec_file
s'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in`run'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in`invoke'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/bin/rspec:23:in`load'
        from C:/Ruby22/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'`

Answer (score 0):

The gemspec files are normally used when you are creating a Ruby gem, and contains the metadata about the Gem you are creating.

when you use `bundle install` it requires a `Gemfile` in the directory. The `Gemfile` works as a manifest file for the gems required for the project in the directory. It is possible that `chef exec` is looking for this file and will only work with gems specified here.

Try creating a `Gemfile` with the content

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rspec'
gem 'chefspec'
```

you should list other gems you are using in the file.
and then run `bundle install`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Hassan. I have created a file named `chefspec.gemfile` and used the content you mentioned. However when I run `bundle install` from the location of the file I still get the error `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

Comment: The file name is important here I believe, by default it must be `Gemfile`. if you prefer to keep it as `chefspec.gemfile` then you will need to pass the location of the file when you run `bundle install` On unix based OS you an provide an environment variable to bundle by running `BUNDLE_GEMFILE=path/to/gemfile bundle install`. Not sure if its the same on windows. Also note you will always have to define `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` for commands the gemfile is needed.